# Device orientation in iOS 6 iphone issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi I have an Tab Bar based application. When I click on the third tab,the view which opens up has a tableview (`AggregateMediaViewController`). On didSelect of the rows, I open a video using `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. I want to set the the orientation of the this video whenever the orientation of the device changes.
     I created a subclass of `UITabbarController` called `OrientationTabBarController`:

```
@implementation OrientationTabBarControllerViewController
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    NSLog(@"in shouldAutorotate tabbar is %@", self.viewControllers);

    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

In the appDidFifnishLaunching:
    [window setRootViewController:tabBarController];
where the tabBarController is a subclass of OrientationTabBarController.

In AggregateMediaViewController, I have the following code:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    NSLog(@"in shouldAutorotate of media");
    return YES;
}

-(NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {    
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

But when I run the application, orientation does not work :(    Please Help

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass your parent controller and add rotation methods of your `UIViewController`. In your case it is UITabBarController. And set it as rootViewController in appDelegate:

```
[self.window setRootViewController:_myTabBarController];
```

Comment: hi,With the above changes, orientation works but I face a 20 pixels issue in some of the screens. But if I remove the above line, 20 pixels issue is resolved but the orientation does not works. Plesae help!!!!